# How to prove for a finite group that $| \langle g \rangle|=o(g)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

How to prove for a finite group that $|\langle g \rangle|=o(g)$?

I really don't know how to show that this is true I tried to say let $o(g)=m$ and then show that $|\langle g \rangle|$ has exactly $m$ elements but I wasn't even sure it did because it would contain the elements $g^0,...g^{m-1}$ so that would mean it's true but what about $g^{-1}$ and the other elements with negative coefficients so it seems like it would actually be bigger than $m$?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to the definition of the generate group. There exists a minimum integer in which one element of group $G$ is powered to, to become $e$ or identity element. So there exists one element which generates the whole group.

Comment: If $o(g) = m$, what does that imply about $g g^{m-1}$? This should tell you that you've already included $g^{-1}$ in your list. You can say similar things for other negative powers.

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: What's "$G$"? It is not true that the cardinality of the group generated by a set $G$ is always equal to the order of some element $g$.

Comment: I feel like it's pretty clear that the original $G$ should have been $g$, so I changed it.

Comment: The OP has re-asked the question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714862/how-to-prove-for-a-finite-group-that-langle-g-rangle-og

Answer (score 1):

Define $\varphi:\mathbb Z \to G$ 
$$\varphi(n)=g^n$$ then
$$\langle g \rangle=im(\varphi)$$

By definition if $o(g)=m$, then $g^n=e$ and for every $1\leq k < m\quad g^n \neq e$.

So $$\ker\varphi=m\mathbb Z$$ Thus $$ \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\cong im(\varphi)=  \langle g \rangle$$ and $$|\langle g \rangle| = |\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z|=m=o(g)$$