# How to prove for a finite group that $|\langle g \rangle|=o(g)$?

Tags: group-theory

**Please note:** I posted this question about an hour ago on my account (I just made it as I am new to the site). I revisited my post and saw that I had not given definitions of what I was asking (I thought they were common notations) and it would not let me edit the post for some reason so I will ask here now and hopefully someone can delete the other thread.

How to prove for a finite group $G$ that $|\langle g \rangle|=o(g)$?

Here are the definitions:

Let $G$ be a finite group and $g \in G$

$o(g)$ is the smallest $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $g^m=e$ (the identity element of the group). (If such an $m$ exists)

$\langle g \rangle=\{g^m : m \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

I really don't know how to show that this is true I tried to say let $o(g)=m$ and then show that $|\langle g \rangle|$ has exactly $m$ elements but I wasn't even sure it did because it would contain the elements $g^0,...g^{m-1}$ so that would mean it's true but what about $g^{-1}$ and the other elements with negative coefficients so it seems like it would actually be bigger than $m$?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to give a link to the earlier posting:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714776/how-to-prove-for-a-finite-group-that-langle-g-rangle-og  The problem may be that you need to register your account.

Comment: Well $g^{-1}$ would be $g^{m-1}$ as $gg^{m-1}=g^m=1$.

Comment: See my answer for the duplicate question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714776/how-to-prove-for-a-finite-group-that-langle-g-rangle-og/1714794#1714794

Comment: Whoever downvoted is there any need really? I explained my situation I'm just after some help which I have now received no need to get your panties in a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove easily that $\langle g\rangle=\{g,g^2,\ldots,g^m=e\}:=G'$ where $m$ is the order of $g$. To do so, notice that $G'\subseteq \langle g \rangle$ by definition.

To prove the other contenence, note that if $x\in \langle g \rangle$, then $x=g^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Use euclidean algorithm to write $k=mq+r$ for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0<r<m$. Then we would have $$x=g^k=g^{mq+r}=(g^m)^q\cdot g^r=e^q\cdot g^r=g^r\in G'$$

Comment: Brilliant. I have been pondering this question for a few hours now and it has just clicked. Thank you very much I will accept answer as soon as it will let me.