Why is the order of an element equal to the order of the group it generates?
I've found this post Prove the order of an element is the order of the group but this does not help me.
Let G be a finite group (G,$\circ$) and a $\in$ G.
$ \langle a \rangle $ = {$a^z$ :  z $\in \mathbb{Z}$}.
ord(a) = min{$a^n$ :  n $\in \mathbb{N+}$} --> smallest integer n.
I've read everywhere that:
The order of an element is equal to the order of the group it generates:
ord(a) = |$ \langle a \rangle $|
I understand that this is true but have not seen proof yet.
Let's say ord(a) = 3
Let's say e is the neutral Element.
Let's say you calculate $ \langle a \rangle $:
For me visually it kind of looks like this:
$$
a^{-x} \circ{}...{}a^{-4}=e
$$
$$
{}\circ{}a^{-3}{}\circ{}a^{-2}{}\circ{}a^{-1}{}\circ{}a^0=e
$$
$$
{}\circ{}a^1{}\circ{}a^2{}\circ{}a^3{}\circ{}a^4=e
$$
$$
{}\circ{}a^5{}\circ{}a^6{}\circ{}a^7{}\circ{}a^8=e
$$
$$
{}\circ{}...
$$
I can understand why $a^1{}\circ{}a^2{}\circ{}a^3{} = {}a^5{}\circ{}a^6{}\circ{}a^7$
since $a^4 = e$ you basically start at the beginning with $a^5 = a^1$ ...
but how can you be sure/prove that values for negative z (operation on inverse elements) are also equal to the positive values:
$a^{-3}{}\circ{}a^{-2}{}\circ{}a^{-1} = a^1{}\circ{}a^2{}\circ{}a^3{}$?
How can you be sure that for an finite group calculating $a^z$ with $z < 0$ does not produce values that  $a^z$ with $0 < z$ does not?
For an element that is a generator of G that is clear for, because |$ \langle a \rangle $| cannot be greater than |G|, but if a is not a generator of G how do you prove that the operation on the inverse element $a^{-1}$ produces the same results as on the element a.
If this is the case, which apparently is, then for finite groups you could write $ \langle a \rangle $ = {$a^n$ :  n $\in \mathbb{N}$} instead of $ \langle a \rangle $ = {$a^z$ :  z $\in \mathbb{Z}$}.
The definition of $ \langle a \rangle $ = {$a^z$ :  z $\in \mathbb{Z}$} with $\mathbb{Z}$ seems only necessary for infinite groups like ($\mathbb{Z}$,+), doesn't it?
Thank you very much for any help.

This question is a duplicate of: How to prove for a finite group that $|\langle g \rangle|=o(g)$?. Found using Approach$0$ https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C OR content%3A%24%7C%5Clangle g%5Crangle%7C%3D%5Ctext%7Bord%7D(g)%24&p=1 For instance if ord$(a)=3$ then $a^{-10}=a^2$ because $-10=3(-4)+2$, so $$a^{-10}=(a^3)^{-4}a^2=a^2.$$

Suppose that $ord(a) = n$ for some integer $n > 0$.
Then $a^n =e$. Thus $a \circ a^{n-1} = e$, and multiplying both sides with $a^{-1}$ gives you $$a^{-1} = a^{n-1}.$$ Now raising both powers by some integer $k > 0$, you have $$a^{-k} = a^{k(n-1)}.$$ (Here we have used the fact that $(a^{-1})^k = a^{-k}$.)
So indeed we can write the negative powers $a^{z}$ ($z < 0$) in terms of positive powers.
About the last part of your question; if $n = ord(a)$ is finite, then $$\langle a \rangle = \{a^k : 0 \leq k < n\}.$$ So indeed $|\langle a \rangle| = n = ord(a)$ in this case. For a finite group, the order of an element is always finite.
In the case where $ord(a)$ is infinite, you have $\langle a \rangle = \{a^k : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. In this case there are no repetitions among the powers of $a$, meaning that $a^i = a^j$ if and only if $i = j$.

I deleted my answer because it was a duplicate, as well as the question: see
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714862/how-to-prove-for-a-finite-group-that-langle-g-rangle-og.

I understand it now. And for me you have explained it in a more comprehensible way than the answer in the duplicate thread. So thank you very much for your perfect answer :).
